# Snake not moving properly for pixel Snake Game

Tags: javascript, arrays, html5-canvas

Why isn't my snake properly moving? h is the head. The segments always seem to collapse into each other all getting set to the head coords. I thought it'd be as simple as remove from the back and add to the front but I guess not. Any help?

```js
        this.segments.forEach(seg => s.setPixel(seg.x, seg.y, 1));

        const h = [...this.segments][0];

        h.x += this.vX;
        h.y += this.vY;

        this.segments.unshift(h);
        this.segments.pop();
```

Comment: You're altering the first segment then putting at the first position, and removing the last. I think you want `h = this.segments.pop()` and remove your last line.

Comment: This certainly won't fix your problem, but why use spread syntax in `const h = [...this.segments][0]`? Shouldn't `const h = this.segments[0]` work just fine?

Comment: @ArleighHix It kind of works. Although pop removes the last index of the array which would be the tail so I wouldn't want to set the head variable to the tail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe the problem is that you are failing to properly **clone** the head.

```
const h = [...this.segments][0];
```

The above assigns the first element in a newly created Array that still has the exact same objects inside. Try using the `Object.assign()` method:

```
        this.segments.forEach(seg => s.setPixel(seg.x, seg.y, 1));

        const h = Object.assign({}, this.segments[0]);

        h.x += this.vX;
        h.y += this.vY;

        this.segments.unshift(h);
        this.segments.pop();
```

https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/70-3-ways-to-clone-objects/#_1-using-spread
https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/70-3-ways-to-clone-objects/#_2-using-object-assign

Comment: Wow thanks that worked! Im going to look into Object.assign.